# Парсинг html сложной по структуре сайта

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день! У меня проблема возникла такая, надо распарсить сайт и дернуть оттуда нужные значения. Как уже написал в заголовке структура сайта сложная, потому парсинг через регулярные выражения скорее всего отпадает, так как они не всегда срабатывают, где есть разные структуры данных. Остается вариант парсинг через DOM. Кто может дать пример как например из интернет-магазина дернуть заголовки, ссылки и цены товаров (Самое простое пока предполагаю)исходя из того что страниц может быть несколько с товарами их все надо перебрать. Структура например отдельного товара такая обрамленная в отдельный div:

```
<div class="product-tile showcompare">
  <div class="product-tile-description">
   <h2 class="product-tile-title"><span class="text-cutter-wrapper"><a href="" class="product-tile-title-link" data-ga-track="false" data-track-event="click" data-track-category="add_to_cart_pop_up" data-track action="cart_popup_acessories_product_name_link_click" title="Ноутбук-трансформер Acer Aspire R7-572G-74518G1Tass (NX.MMQER.001)" data-track-label="Ноутбук-трансформер Acer Aspire R7-572G-74518G1Tass (NX.MMQER.001)">Ноутбук-трансформер Acer Aspire R7-572G-74518G1Tass</a>
...
</span>

<span>...</span>
</h2>
</div>
...
<div class="star-rating star-rating-large rating-mvideo">                                               <a href="http://novosibirsk.************/products/noutbuk-transformer-acer-aspire-r7-572g-74518g1tass-nx-mmqer-001-30020309?showReviewTab=true" class="star-rating-canvas-link">
в корзину</a>
</div>
...
</div>
```

Что-то примерно такого рода структура. Как лучше дернуть заголовок товара например? Брать тег h2 или span или ссылку a брать, чтобы взять заголовок?

Первое что приходит на ум это использовать функцию `file_get_contents`. После которой логично было бы распарсить структуру сайта. Подскажите удобные библиотеки для этого дела, и желательно пример, как правильно парсить документ, если есть много вложенных блоков разного рода, указывающие на один лишь текст в итоге.

Comment: php dom parser tutorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Библиотеку качаем тут http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/

```
   require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$data = file_get_html($url);

foreach($data->find('product-tile-title-link') as $title){
        echo '<p>'.$title->plaintext.'</p>';
    }
```

Описание библиотеки http://xdan.ru/Uchimsya-parsit-saity-s-bibliotekoi-PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser.html

> Подскажите удобные библиотеки для
> этого дела, и желательно пример, как
> правильно парсить документ, если есть
> много вложенных блоков разного рода,
> указывающие на один лишь текст в
> итоге.

В этой библиотеке есть встроеные функции для этого пример:

```
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
echo $html; // выведет <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>;
$e = $html->find("div", 0);
echo $e->tag; // Вернет: "div"
echo $e->outertext; // Вернет: <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>
echo $e->innertext; // Вернет: foo <b>bar</b>
echo $e->plaintext; // Вернет: foo bar
```

Есть более сложные ситуации почитайте про дочерние элементы, а потом ищите по ним

http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/dochernie-selektory

Comment: библиотека очень удобная и простая с освоении. Но когда вам придется обрабатывать большие объемы данных, вы столкнетесь с проблемами по скорости работы данной библиотеки.
как вариант еще есть nokogiri

Comment: Набрел буквально вчера на [эту статейку][1], где пусть и не детально, но проводится сравнение некоторых библиотек для парсинга. Может кому будет интересно.

   [1]:http://www.inattack.ru/article/php-sravnenie-bibliotek-dlya-parsinga/641.html

Comment: @IntegralAL, во первых элемент у вас не правильно указан.


('simple1')

Вы извлекаете класс, а классы указываются через точку ('.simple1').

Сейчас посмотрю более подробней ваш код

---
p.s 

      $url_site = "http://localhost/ks/2.html";
      $data_site = file_get_html($url_site);
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($data_site->find('.simple1') as $title)
      {
         echo '<p>'.$title->plaintext.' test </p>';
         $i++;
      }
      echo '<br/>Operation execute : '.$i.'-th';
       echo ' Content site: '.$data_site;


вот так у меня работает

Comment: Вы просто точно также в примере без точки писали класс (это про find говорю), к которому обращались. Если это в этом проблема, то спасибо...

Comment: В связи с решением этой же проблемы возник еще один вопрос, например есть форма на html странице, как узнать какой пункт checkbox или Radiobutton отмечен? Это надо для того чтобы извлекать данные с интернет-магазина по категориям определенным...

Comment: @IntegralAL, читайте документацию, примеры на ХК не всегда рабочие, оно того и не требует. Селекторы везде похожие: либо это css селекторы, либо jquery селекторы. То, как выбирать элементы с классом подходит и для jquery и для css и для simplehtmldom.  
Данные, которые обрабатываются любыми парсерами, в частности simplehtmldom, не выполняющими скрипты при парсинге, парсят данные как есть. Т.е. если в разметке указан выделенный элемент (chechd для radio или checkbox), то и обращайтесь к соответствующим атрибутам. В противном случае вам надо использовать другие методы, которые учитывают динамик